# How to merge files with partial matches of filename to numeric range in ImageMagick

Tags: batch-file, cmd, imagemagick, tiff, imagemagick-convert

There are a list of numbered files:

```
out0001.tif, out0002.tif, ..., out0100.tif, out0101.tif, ..., out2300.tif
```

And I'd like to merged them into layered tif (using ImageMagick convert) that should contain 100 layers. E. g.

```
merged_1-100.tif, merged_100-200.tif, ...
```

When I run the following cmd, it try to group all tifs in one huge, but I need only first hundred:

```
convert out00??.tif out0100.tif -adjoin merged_1-100.tif
```

What I need to modify in the command?

Comment: I know. 00?? should match to 0001...0099, and after that I add 0100.

Comment: Have you tried to see if `out%04d.tif[1-100]` works, remembering that in a batch file the `%` character requires doubling.

Comment: It says: "convert: no image defined 'merged_1-100.tif'"

Comment: I would advise that you both read the extensive man' pages for your particular task, as well as providing for the community, updates within your question. I did not offer you a full command, yet you've replied telling me it errors out. We have no idea what you tried when it did so. You are not a new member here, so should by now know how best to present your problem.

Comment: out*.tif[0-99] will get the first 100 files in alphabetic order.

Comment: Do you really want image100 in both the 1..100 and the 100..200 sets? Do you have WSL, MSYS, Cygwin or anything sane and less arcane than Windows CMD32?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using a batch file.

```
@echo off

set file_list=
set /a start_index=1
set /a finish_index=100

for /l %%G in (%start_index%,1,%finish_index%) do call :make-filelist %%G

rem Check
echo %file_list%

pause

rem Make conversion
convert %file_list% -adjoin merged_%start_index%-%finish_index%.tif

goto :eof


:make-filelist
    rem Add leading zeros
    set "fn=0000%1"
    set "fn=%fn:~-4%"
    
    rem Add filename to list of files
    set "file_list=%file_list%out%fn%.tif "
    goto :eof
```

It allows using any range of file indexes. To do so it is necessary to change `start_index` and `finish_index`.

Comment: Your solution has a couple drawbacks. It generates just _one_ output file (with 100 layers). This means that you need to modify the code 23 times in order to generate the 23 output files described in the question. Also, the names of the generated output files show they in the wrong order... See [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75498061/778560)

Comment: No, to generate 23 output files I'll add a second loop, that is not presented in the code. Code shows only the inner part of the loop, it shows how to convert files form start_index to stop_index. It is enought ti solve the task.

Answer (score 0):

This solution process *all files* existent on disk and automatically generates the correct (ordered) names for the output files.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "hundred=100"

:nextHundred
if not exist out%hundred:~1%01.tif goto :EOF

echo Merging hundred %hundred:~1%
set /A "next=hundred+1"
convert out%hundred:~1%*.tif[0-99] out%next:~1%00.tif -adjoin merged_%hundred:~1%01-%next:~1%00

set "hundred=%next%"
goto nextHundred
```

I have *not* tested this solution because I have not `convert` application nor data files. This solution relies on the *"convert out*.tif[0-99] will get the first 100 files in alphabetic order"* comment posted by the OP.

Comment: _convert out*.tif[0-99]_ do not work.